# ata1: COMRESET failed (errno= -16) primary disk, but device is not broken

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ssd

Summary:
I have a principal SSD with 2 partitions, one with Ubuntu 20 and the other one with Windows. Yesterday, I tried to boot linux but it fails. Windows fails too. I recently updated Windows, but I do not remember if I used the laptop without problems after it.

When I boot Ubuntu, I get the following error:

```
ata3: COMRESET failed (errno= -16)
ata3: reset failed, giving up
....
ALERT! UUID=93b28... does not exists, dropping to shell.
```

I have read online and it could be that the disk is broken, but the point is that UUID refers to the SSD in which the grub and Ubuntu are installed. I can also see the device booting from a USB with Linux and access the files. But I can not boot any of the systems.

If I run fsck on it, with `sudo fsck /dev/sdb`, I get:

```
ext2fs_open2(): Incorrect magic number in the superblock
fsck.ext2: Incorrect superblock, attempting to back up blocks...
fsck.ext2: Incorrect magic number in the superblock while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.
If the device is valid and actually contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem
(and not swap, ufs, or another type), then the superblock is
corrupted; you might try running e2fsck with an alternative superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

A GPT partition table has been found on /dev/sdb
```

If I execute the later command on /dev/sdb5, I get the following:

```
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sdb5: recovering journal
e2fsck: cannot set blocksize on /dev/sdb5

/dev/sdb5: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

/dev/sdb5: ********** WARNING: File system still has errors ***********
```

Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 server installation?  I see you trying to `fsck` a device (sdb), on drives (sdb) there are usually partitions (sdb1, sdb2..) on which the file-system lives which is what you `fsck`. Also note `fsck` is the command for many file-systems, but cannot fix all (*other specific check commands exist for some file-systems*) but you gave no file-system specifics.